# Get data from jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby, nokogiri

I have a problem getting data using nokogiri with this code:

```
def run
    # load HTML content to doc
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@link))
    cells =  doc.css('div#z_full_column > div.content')
    puts cells # just to see what i've got while running code
end
```

from this website:

http://www.staples.com/sbd/cre/marketing/back-to-school/back-to-school-deals/weekly-deals.html

All data is gone. I only see `<div class="content"></div>`. I tried to put `sleep 5` in each code, but it's useless. Maybe problem here is caused by jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Go to that URL in your browser, then look at the HTML in your browser using View>Source (or comparable), then Edit>Find and type in `class="content"`, and you will see this:

```
<div class="content"></div>



</div>
```

Then if you comb through all the Javascript scripts included on the page, you will probably find one that adds some content to that `<div>`.  Nokogiri has no idea what JavaScript does to the original HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line, which I assume is from the OpenURI class:

```
open(@link)
```

Unfortunately, OpenURI does not support JavaScript. That means that anything on the page that is loaded via jQuery will not be seen by OpenURI. This then means that the JavaScript/jQuery loaded content does not get passed to Nokogiri.

I would suggest switching to a gem that supports driving a real browser, which will support JavaScript. Some of the popular gems include Watir, Selenium-Webdriver and Capybara. I prefer Watir due to its intuitive API.

Your example using Watir would be:

```
require 'watir'

# Open a firefox browser
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

# Go to the url
browser.goto 'http://www.staples.com/sbd/cre/marketing/back-to-school/back-to-school-deals/weekly-deals.html'

# Get the name of the displayed products
products = browser.div(:class => 'content').divs(:class => 'z_prod_mod')
puts products.collect{ |p| p.h3.text }
#=> StaplesÂ® 1-subject notebook, 8" x 10.5", wide rule, 70 sheets
#=> "RoseArt Â® crayons, 24/pack
#=> etc

# Close the browser
browser.close
```

Comment: [OpenURI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html) isn't a gem, it's part of Ruby's Std-lib. "open-uri does not support javascript"? OpenURI doesn't care WHAT the content is, it only retrieves what is returned to it. What WE do with that content is up to us. If it's JavaScript being returned, OpenURI will faithfully return it. The problem with the OP's code is that Nokogiri won't parse JavaScript.

Comment: Nice but it runs slowly because it must open the browser